# How to extract words between 2 parentheses in Unix/ Linux?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, awk, sas

I have a SAS dataset with the list of queries as one of the variable. Below is one of the variable value:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT Table1 file2.txt file.txt QUEUES QDefinitions
Parameters TRAP-Deposit-DSTran.dat.2016-08-07 FROM CS_CASE WHERE 
ANT_CD='FI_BASE_TENANT')t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON 
t2.CASE_ID=t1.CASE_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 t3 ON 
t3.SERVICE_XID=t1.SERVICE_XID LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 t4 ON 
t4.SERVICE_ID=t1.SERVICE_ID WHERE ( t1.CASESTATUs_CD = (NEW) OR 
t1.CASE_STATUS_CD = (OPEN) )
AND ( t3.SEARCH_VALUE = (HighVal_Ind) AND t3.SEARCH_VALUE_N <= 3 ) AND 
( t4.SEARCH_VALUE_Nm = (Curr_Strategy) AND t4.SEARCH_STRG = (095) ) 
GROUP BY t1.CASE_REFERENCE,t2.LAST_SCRFP,t1.SERVICE_ID 
ORDER BY t2.LAST_SCRFP DESC
```

What I want to do is I want to put the value enter code here's in `()` as `(' ')`.

For example:

```
WHERE ( t1.CASESTATUs_CD = (NEW) OR t1.CASE_STATUS_CD = (OPEN) )
```

I want to change this to:

```
WHERE ( t1.CASESTATUs_CD = ('NEW') OR t1.CASE_STATUS_CD = ('OPEN') )
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is completely unreadable. Please read the [markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and then [edit] your question to make code look like code. You should also explain what you have tried so far to solve your problem, and how that has failed.

Comment: [edit] your question to clarify what `list of queries as one of the variable` means. Are you saying that block of text is contained in a shell variable? If so why and where did it come from? How should a script identify the text inside parens that you wanted quoted separately from the text inside parens that you don't want quoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear but MAYBE this is what you want:

```
$ sed -E 's/\(([^()]+)\)/('\''\1'\'')/g' file
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT Table1 file2.txt file.txt QUEUES QDefinitions
Parameters TRAP-Deposit-DSTran.dat.2016-08-07 FROM CS_CASE WHERE
ANT_CD='FI_BASE_TENANT')t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON
t2.CASE_ID=t1.CASE_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 t3 ON
t3.SERVICE_XID=t1.SERVICE_XID LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 t4 ON
t4.SERVICE_ID=t1.SERVICE_ID WHERE ( t1.CASESTATUs_CD = ('NEW') OR
t1.CASE_STATUS_CD = ('OPEN') )
AND ( t3.SEARCH_VALUE = ('HighVal_Ind') AND t3.SEARCH_VALUE_N <= 3 ) AND
( t4.SEARCH_VALUE_Nm = ('Curr_Strategy') AND t4.SEARCH_STRG = ('095') )
GROUP BY t1.CASE_REFERENCE,t2.LAST_SCRFP,t1.SERVICE_ID
ORDER BY t2.LAST_SCRFP DESC
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT Table1 file2.txt file.txt QUEUES QDefinitions
Parameters TRAP-Deposit-DSTran.dat.2016-08-07 FROM CS_CASE WHERE
ANT_CD='FI_BASE_TENANT')t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON
t2.CASE_ID=t1.CASE_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 t3 ON
t3.SERVICE_XID=t1.SERVICE_XID LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 t4 ON
t4.SERVICE_ID=t1.SERVICE_ID WHERE ( t1.CASESTATUs_CD = (NEW) OR
t1.CASE_STATUS_CD = (OPEN) )
AND ( t3.SEARCH_VALUE = (HighVal_Ind) AND t3.SEARCH_VALUE_N <= 3 ) AND
( t4.SEARCH_VALUE_Nm = (Curr_Strategy) AND t4.SEARCH_STRG = (095) )
GROUP BY t1.CASE_REFERENCE,t2.LAST_SCRFP,t1.SERVICE_ID
ORDER BY t2.LAST_SCRFP DESC
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but when I ran the command it gives an extra quotations - before - (' Select Table1 and after ANT_CD='FI_BASE_TENANT' '), Also it didn't quote HighVal_Ind in my case. Thanks for help.

Comment: For the first issue, one possible solution would be to add `'\''` within the bracket expression (`[^()'\'']`), for the 2nd - that's not possible given the input you posted so if you have some other input that's producing that behavior then you need to include THAT input in your question.

Comment: Ed, thank you very much, this function worked for me -- sed -E 's/\(([^(,$1)'\'']+)\)/('\''\1'\'')/g' -- One more question I promise it will be my final question. Is there any way we can put the values in string for the below condition-- WHERE ( t1.CASESTATUs_CD = (NEW, OLD, CLOSED, PENDING)  )                                                                                                Change to - WHERE ( t1.CASESTATUs_CD = ('NEW', 'OLD', 'CLOSED', 'PENDING')  )

Comment: Of course but that's a completely different problem to the one you posted. If you want to solve THAT completely different problem then that'll take a completely different type of solution so post a new question and this time make sure the sample input you post truly covers ALL of your used cases (especially if what you want quoted can be split across lines).

Answer (score 0):

This is best solved using regular expression. In SAS this is done using the `prxchange` function. Assuming you have no whitespace in your conditions, we check for brackets with no whitespace in between. Adjust the function if there are other conditions.

```
data query;
    length want $3000;
    have= 
        "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT Table1 file2.txt file.txt QUEUES QDefinitions
        Parameters TRAP-Deposit-DSTran.dat.2016-08-07 FROM CS_CASE WHERE 
        ANT_CD='FI_BASE_TENANT')t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON 
        t2.CASE_ID=t1.CASE_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 t3 ON 
        t3.SERVICE_XID=t1.SERVICE_XID LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 t4 ON 
        t4.SERVICE_ID=t1.SERVICE_ID WHERE ( t1.CASESTATUs_CD = (NEW) OR 
        t1.CASE_STATUS_CD = (OPEN) )
        AND ( t3.SEARCH_VALUE = (HighVal_Ind) AND t3.SEARCH_VALUE_N <= 3 ) AND 
        ( t4.SEARCH_VALUE_Nm = (Curr_Strategy) AND t4.SEARCH_STRG = (095) ) 
        GROUP BY t1.CASE_REFERENCE,t2.LAST_SCRFP,t1.SERVICE_ID 
        ORDER BY t2.LAST_SCRFP DESC";
    want =  prxchange("s/\(([^ ]+)\)/('\1')/", -1, have); 
run;
```