# Replace Words in the parentheses to put into quotations

Tags: linux, perl, awk, sed, sas

I want to replace the words in the parentheses to put into quotations. 
My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955980/extract-words-between-2-parentheses-in-unix-linux) had one value in parentheses. This one is the same as my previous question, but thought of a scenario where I will have multiple values in parentheses.

Below is the data I have in one of the variable data -

```
SELECT          * 
FROM            ( 
                       SELECT table1 file2.txt file.txt queues qdefinitions parameters trap-deposit-dstran.dat.2016-08-07 
                       FROM   cs_case 
                       WHERE  ant_cd='FI_BASE_TENANT') t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 
ON              t2.case_id=t1.case_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 
ON              t3.service_xid=t1.service_xid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 t4 
ON              t4.service_id=t1.service_id 
WHERE           ( 
                                t1.casestatus_cd = (new,retired,pending,OPEN,closed) 
                OR              t1.case_status_num = (1,2,3,4) ) 
GROUP BY        t1.case_reference, 
                t2.last_scrfp, 
                t1.service_id 
ORDER BY        t2.last_scrfp DESC
```

Here is what I want.

```
SELECT          * 
FROM            ( 
                       SELECT table1 file2.txt file.txt queues qdefinitions parameters trap-deposit-dstran.dat.2016-08-07 
                       FROM   cs_case 
                       WHERE  ant_cd='FI_BASE_TENANT') t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 
ON              t2.case_id=t1.case_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 
ON              t3.service_xid=t1.service_xid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 t4 
ON              t4.service_id=t1.service_id 
WHERE           ( 
                                t1.casestatus_cd = ('NEW','RETIRED','PENDING','OPEN','CLOSED') 
                or              t1.case_status_num = (1,2,3,4) ) 
GROUP BY        t1.case_reference, 
                t2.last_scrfp, 
                t1.service_id 
ORDER BY        t2.last_scrfp DESC
```

Previously I have used sed command as below

```
sed -E 's/\(([^(,$1)'\'']+)\)/('\''\1'\'')/g' Filename.txt
```

Comment: Hi Nick, as previously pointed out you should use [markup](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in your questions to make things clearer. Last time I formatted it for you, but I think you should at least learn if you are going to post multiple questions.

Comment: You should explain why this question is different than your [last one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38955980/176646). I was going to vote to close as a duplicate until I saw [Ed Morton's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955980/extract-words-between-2-parentheses-in-unix-linux#comment65306083_38956931) suggesting you ask a new question.

Comment: My Previous question had one value in parentheses. Ed Morton's commented a command where I modified little bit. This one is the same as my previous question, but thought of a scenario where I will have multiple values in parentheses.
I am trying to automate the process in SAS where I will run unix commands to replace the query using sed command. Hope that make sense.

Comment: @Nick Please [edit] that info into your question.

Comment: What is the source of this text that you are modifying? Why does the text need to have quotes inserted? Is this a one time thing or do you have a lot of these invalid text files?  Also your example SQL is invalid since you cannot use `=` to test if a value is in a list, need to use IN operator instead. `t1.case_status_num IN (1,2,3,4)`

Comment: What's the rule that explains why `(new,retired,pending,OPEN,closed)` gets it's elements quoted but `(1,2,3,4)` doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Using a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38962950/791908) provided by [sln](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557597/sln) using [Regex Quote-Like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), to provide readability/maintainability.

Plus another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38963554/791908) provided by [mob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mob) for an elegant quoting mechanism.

Plus some coding to put it all together for your specific senario:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

# create a regex quote-like string for our match
my $rx = qr{\(([^)]+)\)};

# step through STDIN
while(<>) {

    # Replace matching (...) sections by passing the matched part
    # to QuoteText() and subsituting the result it returns.
    #
    # Note the 'e' and 'g' flags to s///, e enables "extended"
    # operations which allows us to call QuoteText() and g 
    # replaces _all_ occurances on a line
    s/$rx/QuoteText($1)/eg;

    # print out the line (post any possible substitutions)
    print;
}

sub QuoteText {
    my $text = shift;

    # the variable we will use to return our result
    my $result;

    # Does the text contain commas and also contains alphabetical characters?   
    if($text =~ /,/ && $text =~ /[a-z]/i) {

        # split up the text around commas, then rejoin them with the 
        # string ',', and then prepend and append a single quote 
        # at the begining and end of line. So one,two becomes 'one','two'
        $result = q/'/ . join(q/','/, split (',', $text)) . q/'/;

    # The word _only_ contains numbers, spaces and commas, leave as is
    } elsif($text =~ /^[\s\d,]+$/i) {
        $result = $text;

    # We possibly have just a single word? default to quoting the word
    } else {
        $result = qq/'$text'/;
    }

    # return our result wrapped in ()'s
    return "($result)";
}
```

Note: I've not uppercased the quoted words. You will need to `map` and `uc` the parts of the `split` if you want to achieve that. Also in the case where the words to be quoted is a mixture of numbers and words, it will end up quoting all numbers and words. If this is a problem, then this may be better served by splitting the words, looping over each word, evalutaing it's content to see if it needs quoting and then concatenating the result to the returned string.

Answer (score 0):

That's no longer a simple substitution on individual lines so it's no longer a job for sed, it's a job for awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="^$"; ORS="" }
{
    while ( match($0,/(=\s*\()([^()]+)(\))/,a) ) {
        if ( a[2] ~ /[^0-9,]/) {
            gsub(/,/,"\047,\047",a[2])
            a[2] = "\047" toupper(a[2]) "\047"
        }
        print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[1] a[2] a[3]
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
SELECT          *
FROM            (
                       SELECT table1 file2.txt file.txt queues qdefinitions parameters
trap-deposit-dstran.dat.2016-08-07
                       FROM   cs_case
                       WHERE  ant_cd='FI_BASE_TENANT') t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON              t2.case_id=t1.case_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3
ON              t3.service_xid=t1.service_xid
LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 t4
ON              t4.service_id=t1.service_id
WHERE           (
                                t1.casestatus_cd = ('NEW','RETIRED','PENDING','OPEN','CLOSED')
                OR              t1.case_status_num = (1,2,3,4) )
GROUP BY        t1.case_reference,
                t2.last_scrfp,
                t1.service_id
ORDER BY        t2.last_scrfp DESC
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and multi-char RS.

Answer (score -3):

**WHY ALL THIS INSANE COMPLICATION?**

**How about:**

**$line =~ s/(([^(]+))/"\1"/g;**

Note that the () groups a sub-expression; the ( matches a literal '(' (there's no need to elide a ')'); the [^(]+ matches a set of non-parentheses within the asserted parentheses; the "\1" quotes what was matched, viz., what occurred within the parentheses, excepting parentheses themselves.

Comment: Did you test this? This does not work. Also, perl prefers `$1` to `\1` (avoid warnings of `\1 better written as $1`).

Comment: Yeah, `\1` is intended to be used in the regex; you use `$1` in the replacement text.